# Get the element with the highest priority based on another list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, performance, java-8

I have a list of priorities

```
List<String> priorities = Arrays.asList("NV","PH","OO","DR");
```

And I have a list of Items `List<Item> availableItems` where the Item has an attribute called `type` that can be one of the values from the first list.

So I am working on a method, that returns one element (the highest priority), I was doing something with a comparator and sorting, but I was reading about it and it's said it takes a lot of time since `availableItems` can have a lot of elements, so it might be `O(NLogN)`.

What I am trying to achieve is if there is an element with `type` `NV` return is since is the highest priority, if not the one with `PH` and so on, and if there is no a single one, then return any element of the list, since they don't have, but without using comparators or the cost is not high

Comment: You can achieve this with a single iteration over the unordered list; however, you can only short-circuit if you find ane element with a `type` of `"NV"`

Comment: You could use a TreeMap<Integer, Item> where the integer is a priority number.  1 - NV, 2 - PH, etc.  Then you would just take the first key, value pair.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which includes your attempt, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@Gilbert Le Blanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300257/gilbert-le-blanc) comment.

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<Item0>> groupByType = availableItems.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> priorities.indexOf(item.getType()),
                                                TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));

System.out.println(groupByType.firstEntry().getValue().get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `PriorityQueue` with a index-based Comparator:

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> comparatorByIndex(List<T> list) {
  Map<T, Integer> priority = IntStream.range(0, list.size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(list::get, Function.identity()));
  return Comparator.comparing(k -> priority.getOrDefault(k, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
}
```

And getting the String with highest priority like:

```
List<String> priorities = Arrays.asList("NV","PH","OO","DR");
Queue<String> priorityOrder = new PriorityQueue<>(comparatorByIndex(priorities));
priorityOrder.addAll(availableItems);

String highestPriority = priorityOrder.poll();
```

Comment: The `PriorityQueue` is only useful, if fetching more elements is intended. Otherwise, a simple `Collections.min(availableItems, comparatorByIndex(priorities))` would be enough and have a time complexity of O(n), which seems to be the OP’s concern. Alternatively, `availableItems.stream().min(comparatorByIndex(priorities))`

Comment: @Holger You're right, if you only want only the highest element `Stream#min` or `Collections#min` is the way to go.